# Carbon planet gardens

Tags: science-based, creature-design, aliens, flora, biochemistry

This is a restart of my previous question: let's say there was a carbon planet with life. That means it would use hydrocarbons as a solvent and since the molecules are more complicated, all reactions would be slower. What would the autotrophs be like? To be precise: What color would they be for a photosynthesis equivalent? What shape could they take given what I've said?

Comment: You previous question got closed for lack of details. This one doesn't make any step forward in adding more details. Do you expect any different outcome?

Comment: Ok. Fair enough. I'll edit it

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I feel like both the sun's class/color and the planet's atmosphere will change the photosynthesis color. Could you tell us more about that?

Comment: Also, you're asking 3 questions, all extremely broad. Please remember that on Earth we have a wide array of plant colors and shapes, going from the green of spiky cacti to the multilayered, intricate, (beautiful), orange, deciduous tree leaves (yes, it's not because of photosynthesis, but it's technically part of the tree's life cycle, ie. what we see).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You are focused on the wrong details

As a general rule, evolution will care more about your environment than your building blocks.  If an organism has the capacity to evolve and adapt to its environment, then it does not matter what it is made of, it will try to find the same sorts of solutions as something made of something else.  If your world is Earth like in all respects other than it's carbon content, then the kind of life that evolves there will be almost indistinguishable from Earth based life until you get it under a microscope.

So to find out how your autotrophs will be different, you need to ask yourself how your environment is different:

- Does your planet rain hydrocarbons, or do your autotrophs rely on a different method of getting its hydrocarbon solvents?
- Which hydrocarbon does it use?
- Does this means your planet is much hotter or colder than Earth?
- Does this mean your atmosphere must have certain properties to keep it chemically stable.
- Does this change the kind of star or orbital distant you need?
- Does this create secondary environmental factors that Earth based life does not need to content with, or vise versa, do certain Earth based complications get reduced?

Once you establish how your environment works, then you will know what your autotrophs need to be capable of in order to survive, and that list of capabilities will determine what it looks.